# I am trying to get Eloquent eager loading to work, but it keeps looking for an incorrect column name in the hasMany table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two models. EmailTemplate and EmailBody. The EmailBody has a foreign key of the EmailTemplate id. In my models I have:

```
class EmailTemplate extends Model
<snip>
{
  public fuction emailBody()
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EmailBody'); 
}



class EmailBody extends Model
<snip>
public function emailTemplate()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\EmailTemplate');
}
```

When I try to greedy load the template by including a "->with('emailbody')" clause, I receive the following error:

```
"blah blah... Unknown column 'email_bodys.email_template_id' in where clause....
```

I do not understand why it is looking for email_template_id column. The foreign key in the email_bodys table is simply called 'template_id'. What tells eloquent the name it should look for for the foreign key when it is eager loading? Can I tell it what to use or do i have to design my database around its preconceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is looking for `email_template_id` because it generates the foreign key name based upon the name of the relationship. In this case, `emailTemplate` becomes `email_template_id`. You have two options to resolve this.

**Change the relationship name**

You can simply change the name of the method from `emailTemplate` to `template`.

**OR**

**Specify Key Name**

You could specify the key name on the relationship. You can pass a second argument to the `belongsTo` method. So it would become:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\EmailTemplate', 'template_id');
```